# TLS/SSL connection has been closed (EOF)

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

I'm using this code to perform put/get requests via python:

```
requests.get(*some https url*, verify=False)
```

Server to which I'm trying to connect doesn't accept my Hello and closes the connection.
Server definitely supports TLSv1, 1.2, 1.3.

I've tried python 3.6, 3.7, 3.8 and 3.9 and the error is still the same.

Server side guys are not able to provide any info on TLS level so I only have my pcap files.

In pcap file I see that my hello is not answered by hello from the server, server sends "Warning, User Canceled" and then "Warning, Close Notify".

Comment: Is the URL a public one? It might be easier to debug if others could reproduce it. Did you try accessing the URL with some other tool (such as `curl`, `wget` or simply a browser)? How did that go? Is your system using some kind of proxy? Also note that TLS v1.0 *should no longer be supported* by any sane server, as that protocol is considered unsafe (by many browser manufacturers at least).

Comment: Further to the suggestion to try an alternative tool, you could try `openssl s_client host:443` which will show you what is going on from connection to successful (or unsuccessful) handshake.

Comment: @JoachimSauer it is not public, no proxy is being used.

Comment: @mhawke thanks, will try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by downgrading urllib3 to urllib3-1.24.3, seems there is some trouble with 1.26.2.